# Gapless logging of past events and subscription to new events in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, events, typescript

I would like to populate a database with all the past transfer events and then continuously add them as they happen without a gap between. (In my example I will use console.log instead of adding to database for simplicity)

My current approach is this

```
const contract = new Contract(<address>, <abi>, <provider>)

const past_events = await contract.queryFilter('Transfer')
console.log(past_events)

// Some time might pass in which an event is missed

contract.on('Transfer', (...parameters) => {
  console.log(parameters)
})
```

How can I ensure that I don't have a gap due to an event happening between logging the past events and subscribing to new events?